# How datetime null serialization in json .net 5 blazor

Tags: c#, json, date, blazor

In blazor client side + api

Just to be clear: I want it as generic as possible so this one method in controller executes a stored procedure that can query many tables and return different result sets without knowing of type that this will be parsed into later in frontend wasm. So I cannot return `List<MYclass>` because it will be different every time.

In api controller I have like this to serialize table that have 3 columns

```
ID,  IDSiec,  data
```

The `data` is datetime type, and I serialize this dataTable like this

```
da.Fill(dt);
connection.Close();

List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }

    rows.Add(row);
}

return Ok(rows);
```

and then in wasm

```
class MYclass
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int IDSiec { get; set; }
        public DateTime? data { get; set; }
}
.....

await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<MYclass>>());
```

And if in database all records have this `data` filed then it is ok but if this `data` is null then in json for this record I get

```
"Data":{},
```

and it fails with an error

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable [System.DateTime]. Path: $[0].Data | LineNumber: 0

How should I handle this kind of situation? Force somehow this serializer to send NULL. Object is not nulable so thats why it sends {} instead of null value probably

Sample json out

```
[{"ID":1141818,"IDSiec":94,"Data":{},...}]
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: What does your JSON look like? Why are you using a Datatable at all? Your converting the query results to a DataTable, then to a Dictionary, then to JSON. Why not load `MYClass` objects directly, using EF Core or Dapper? Even looping over the DataReader and creating `MyClass` instances would be faster,use half the memory and be easier to write

Comment: You could replace all this code with `var rows=connection.Query<MyClass>(sql); return Ok(rows);` if you used [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Dapper would also take care of safely opening and. closing the connection, something that isn't done now - if an exception occurs before `connection.Close()` is called, the connection remains open

Comment: updated my quastion with sample and explenation why like this

Comment: That's what Dapper and EF Core already do. You can convert the results to `dynamic` if you want. The current code on the other hand isn't generic at all. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Whatever it is, using a DataTable and DataAdapter to load data isn't relevant

Comment: `Data":{}` ? That's not a `DateTime`. That's an object without properties. The JSON sample is incomplete. In any case, you can do whatever you want with a single line. There's no reason to write your own generic method when the problem is already solved

Comment: If you want to create a "REST API" over a database, 1) you need the schema and 2) that's done too - OData and GraphQL provide exactly this. Even a simple query and `return Ok(rows);` would do

Comment: ...unless you want to do something extremely insecure, like allow the *client* to send queries like `drop table customers` to the server. Don't do that.

Comment: i want allow clien vla this one api controler to exec every stoderprocedure with custom parameters to get diferent datasets.

Comment: You can do that easily with `var rows=conn.Query<dynamic>(someQuery,someParams); return Ok(rows);`.

Comment: Or you can use a `List<dynamic>` instead of a dictionary and create `ExpandoObject` instances with the field names and values you want.

Comment: *one method in controller executes a stored procedure .... return different result sets* - sounds like a **horribly bad design** idea.... that's the typical "everything-but-the-kitchen-sink" approach which is **guaranteed** to be insecure, and cause lots of headaches  ..... my advice: **DON'T DO IT!!** - you need to **KNOW** your data and program accordingly .....

Comment: i known that it is not best practise especialy for complex scenarios but for simple select top(100)* from xx or yy / zz  and just send it to frontend ? without need to change anytking in api ? i think it is perfect for such cases. Im not asking what you think about that just how to easly solve this one small issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    if (dr[col] != null)  // or test against DbNull or something
    {
       row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
}
```

the final answer from the comment below:

```
 if (dr[col] == DBNull.Value) 
    row.Add(col.ColumnName, null); 
 else 
   row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
```

I do agree with the safety concerns raised here. But this answer is about how to handle NULL values from a Db API.

Comment: simple is best - thanks
                            if (dr[col] == DBNull.Value)
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, null);
                            else
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        } solve that

Comment: there is no safety concern here but if anyone have than i would be more then happy to discuss  'this my way' with more detail so someone can point me seciurity hole if there is some.